# How I can deploy Firebase function on heroku for google asistant

Tags: firebase, heroku, npm, dialogflow-es

I have created a simple function for google assistant (`dialogflow`) for firebase function with the next structure:

```
functions/
     node_module/
     index.js
     package-lock.json
     package.json 
firebase.json
```

How I can deploy this function (webhook) on Heroku for using it in Google actions for google home (`dialogflow`). The main problem with firebase is that the firebase doesn't allow sen HTTP request from functions in a free account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only deploy code written for Cloud Functions to the Cloud Functions service itself.  The code absolutely depends on the Cloud Functions scalable infrastructure to work the way that it does.